# catkin_make error when compiling cuda code on TK1

Tags: ros, catkin-make, jetson-tk1, cuda, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile a package that has C++, C, and Cuda code.  I've been able to successfully compile the package on a TX1 with cuda 7.0 but I get a strange compilation error when compiling on my TK1 with cuda 6.5.  Here is the error:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Building NVCC (Device) object darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o
-- Removing /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o
/usr/bin/cmake -E remove /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o
-- Generating dependency file: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.NVCC-depend
/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -M -D__CUDACC__ /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/darknet_ros/src/yolo_kernels.cu -o /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.NVCC-depend -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m32 -DROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"darknet_ros\" -DROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX -DGPU -DOPENCV -Xcompiler ,\"-g\" -arch=sm_32 -O3 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -DNVCC -I/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include -I/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/include -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/darknet_ros/src -I/opt/ros/indigo/include -I/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include
-- Generating temporary cmake readable file: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.depend.tmp
/usr/bin/cmake -D input_file:FILEPATH=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.NVCC-depend -D output_file:FILEPATH=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.depend.tmp -P /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA/make2cmake.cmake
-- Copy if different /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.depend.tmp to /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.depend
/usr/bin/cmake -E copy_if_different /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.depend.tmp /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.depend
-- Removing /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.depend.tmp and /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.NVCC-depend
/usr/bin/cmake -E remove /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.depend.tmp /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.NVCC-depend
-- Generating /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o
/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/darknet_ros/src/yolo_kernels.cu -c -o /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m32 -DROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"darknet_ros\" -DROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX -DGPU -DOPENCV -Xcompiler ,\"-g\" -arch=sm_32 -O3 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -DNVCC -I/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include -I/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/include -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/darknet_ros/src -I/opt/ros/indigo/include -I/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/service_client.h(185): error: expected a ")"

/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/service_client.h(185): error: too few arguments in function call

    /opt/ros/indigo/include/sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h(179): warning: statement is unreachable
    
    /opt/ros/indigo/include/sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h(231): warning: statement is unreachable
    
    2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000009e5_00000000-9_yolo_kernels.compute_20.cpp1.ii".
    -- Removing /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o
    /usr/bin/cmake -E remove /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o
    CMake Error at ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o.cmake:264 (message):
      Error generating file
      /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o
    
    
    make[2]: *** [darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/src/./ROS_interface_generated_yolo_kernels.cu.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [darknet_ros/CMakeFiles/ROS_interface.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

And here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

    project(darknet_ros)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  image_transport
  message_generation
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  bbox.msg
  bbox_array.msg
)
generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
)

set(
    CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
    ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
    -O3 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20
    )
add_definitions(-DGPU -DOPENCV)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
)

include_directories(
  /usr/local/cuda/include
  src

      ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

link_directories(
  /usr/local/cuda/lib
)

cuda_add_executable(ROS_interface 
  src/ROS_interface.cpp

  src/gemm.c            src/utils.c 
  src/cuda.c            src/deconvolutional_layer.c 
      src/convolutional_layer.c     src/list.c 

  src/image.c           src/activations.c 
  src/im2col.c          src/col2im.c 
  src/blas.c            src/crop_layer.c 
  src/dropout_layer.c       src/maxpool_layer.c 
  src/softmax_layer.c       src/data.c 
  src/matrix.c          src/network.c 
  src/connected_layer.c     src/cost_layer.c 
  src/parser.c          src/option_list.c 
  src/detection_layer.c     src/tag.c 
  src/imagenet.c        src/captcha.c 
  src/route_layer.c         src/writing.c 
  src/box.c             src/nightmare.c 
  src/normalization_layer.c     src/avgpool_layer.c 
  src/coco.c            src/dice.c 
  src/yolo.c            src/layer.c 
  src/compare.c         src/classifier.c  
  src/local_layer.c         src/shortcut_layer.c 
  src/activation_layer.c    src/cifar.c
  src/coco_demo.c       src/swag.c
  src/crnn_layer.c      src/go.c
  src/rnn.c         src/rnn_layer.c
  src/rnn_vid.c         

  src/convolutional_kernels.cu  src/deconvolutional_kernels.cu 

  src/activation_kernels.cu     src/im2col_kernels.cu 
  src/col2im_kernels.cu     src/blas_kernels.cu 
  src/crop_layer_kernels.cu     src/dropout_layer_kernels.cu 
  src/maxpool_layer_kernels.cu  src/softmax_layer_kernels.cu 
  src/network_kernels.cu    src/avgpool_layer_kernels.cu 
  src/yolo_kernels.cu)

cuda_add_executable(yolo_object_detector
  src/YOLO_object_detector.cpp

  src/gemm.c                    src/utils.c
  src/cuda.c                    src/deconvolutional_layer.c

  src/convolutional_layer.c     src/list.c
  src/image.c                   src/activations.c
  src/im2col.c                  src/col2im.c
  src/blas.c                    src/crop_layer.c
  src/dropout_layer.c           src/maxpool_layer.c
  src/softmax_layer.c           src/data.c
  src/matrix.c                  src/network.c
  src/connected_layer.c         src/cost_layer.c
  src/parser.c                  src/option_list.c
  src/detection_layer.c         src/tag.c
  src/imagenet.c                src/captcha.c
  src/route_layer.c             src/writing.c
  src/box.c                     src/nightmare.c

  src/normalization_layer.c     src/avgpool_layer.c
  src/yolo_obj_detector.c      src/layer.c
  src/compare.c                 src/classifier.c
  src/local_layer.c             src/shortcut_layer.c
  src/activation_layer.c        src/cifar.c
  src/crnn_layer.c              src/go.c
  src/rnn.c                     src/rnn_layer.c
  src/rnn_vid.c

  src/convolutional_kernels.cu  src/deconvolutional_kernels.cu
  src/activation_kernels.cu     src/im2col_kernels.cu
  src/col2im_kernels.cu         src/blas_kernels.cu
  src/crop_layer_kernels.cu     src/dropout_layer_kernels.cu
  src/maxpool_layer_kernels.cu  src/softmax_layer_kernels.cu
  src/network_kernels.cu        src/avgpool_layer_kernels.cu
  src/yolo_kernels_ROSobj_detector.cu)


target_link_libraries(ROS_interface
   m
   pthread
   stdc++
   cuda 
   cudart 
   cublas 
   curand
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(yolo_object_detector
   m
   pthread
   stdc++
   cuda
   cudart
   cublas
   curand
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Based on the error message, there is something wrong the /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/service_client.h file but when I look at the line where the error is, it is simply a ROS_ERROR message line.

Anyone have any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246194/catkin_make-error-when-compiling-cuda-code-on-tk1/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved.  Don't let ROS libraries get included into the cuda code!!!  Through the linkages of my source code, ROS libraries were being included in cuda code and the cuda compiler was having a hard time interpreting those libraries. By keeping the #include statements for all ROS libraries limited to my C++ code, I was able to compile without issues.

---

Originally posted by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) with karma: 354 on 2016-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0